# Find mutual friends in facebook using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to find the number of mutual friends between two of my friends. Is it possible and what permissions i should tick to get this access token?

I used following query in Graph API Explorer:

```
id1/mutualfriends/id2
```

It returns mutual friends between me and id2. But i want mutual friends between id1 and id2. Both id1 and id2 are my friends.What is the right format of query if it is possible?

If anyone know about it please response.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? was there an error message?

Comment: it returns mutual friends between me and id2(works like: me/mutualfriend/id2 ). But i want mutual friends between id1 and id2(both id1 and id2 are my friends).